# Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile") doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, which copy the content of a website to Excel:

```
Sub HTML_Table_To_Excel()
Dim htm As Object
Dim Tr As Object
Dim Td As Object
Dim Tab1 As Object

Web_URL = "https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar"

'Create HTMLFile Object
 Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

 'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
  With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
 .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
  .send
  HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText 'this is the highlighted part 
   for the error
  End With
 Column_Num_To_Start = 1
 iRow = 1
 iCol = 1
 iTable = 1

  'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format
     For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")
   With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
    For Each Tr In .Rows
        For Each Td In Tr.Cells
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Next Td
    iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
    iRow = iRow + 1
    Next Tr
  End With

 Next Tab1

 MsgBox "Process Completed"
 End Sub
```

This coding was working so well, but now is not working; "a message appear: Run-Time '429': ActiveX component can't create object "  ...... after this, If I select Debug, a part of the code will highlight:

```
  Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't going to be a nice *here you go* answer. At least not at present.

1. `XMLHTTP` request will not work here. The page is dynamically loaded and the content simply isn't there via the method you are using; which is executed before this info is available.
2. You should always use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. You have numerous undeclared variables (e.g. `Web_URL As String`) which will be generated on the fly as variants. And you are not catching what look like either typos/inconsistent variable naming: `Dim htm As Object: Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")`.

   I suspect that you wanted `Set htm = CreateObject("htmlfile")` . This would be an object type consistent with your existing naming and declaration.  `HTML_Content` would be a string, and would not require the `Set` keyword which assigns an object reference. Here, I think you wanted  `HTML_Content = .responseText`, but in fact it is safer to ensure any returned string is unencoded with `HTML_Content = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)`
3. There is only one table of interest, as far as I can see, and it has an id. If you were to continue with your method then after this line: `For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")`, each `Tab1` would be an `HTMLTable` object so you wouldn't need the next line with `iTable` variable. You are using a `For Each Loop` so are already iterating the parent collection. Simply, grab the table by its id: `With .document.getElementById("fxst-calendartable")`. id is the fastest retrieval method available so should be preferred over all other methods when available.
4. The table is either poorly designed or deliberately designed to make scraping difficult. You can neither copy the object `outerHTML` to clipboard and paste the table to Excel, nor simply loop table rows and table cells to get all the content displayed. And the content that is displayed is not in a nice legible fashion. You may have some luck with web queries but in my experience Javascript heavy pages like this don't mix well with data from web queries.

So, with those points in mind:

1. You are going to likely need to use a browser to navigate and ensure page content has loaded e.g.  `While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend`, possibly with some extra explicit wait time
2. It is also likely you will need to inspect the html of the table closely to write something fit for purpose to grab the elements you are interested in, and write them out in a coherent fashion to the page. For example, it is clear you will need to consider the role and placement of div elements within the table for correct alignment of data in your output.
3. You could simply dump the above approach and screen shot the timetable or print it out. Consider whether the effort of coding this is worth it over simply printing the page once a week (unless page is frequently updated).